# How can I get SharePoint app roles with Graph?

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online, azure-app-registration

I am looking for the internal ID for the SharePoint Online application roles, the second on this screenshot:
[image]

For Graph, I an list them like this:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals?$filter=displayName eq 'Microsoft Graph'&$select=displayName,appRoles
```

This returns, among others, the following Graph API role:

```
{
                    "allowedMemberTypes": [
                        "Application"
                    ],
                    "description": "Allow the application to access a subset of site collections without a signed in user.  The specific site collections and the permissions granted will be configured in SharePoint Online.",
                    "displayName": "Access selected site collections",
                    "id": "....",
                    "isEnabled": true,
                    "origin": "Application",
                    "value": "Sites.Selected"
                }
```

The id here is tenant specific. I would like to get the id for the same role, under the SharePoint Online resource. I need this to grant admin consent from our self service tool.

However, I cannot find anything via this endpoint. I listed everything that looks like SharePoint:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals?$filter=startswith(displayName,'SharePoint')&$select=displayName,appRoles
```

but all the appRoles arrays are empty:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#servicePrincipals(displayName,appRoles)",
    "value": [
        {
            "displayName": "SharePoint Home Notifier",
            "appRoles": []
        },
        {
            "displayName": "SharePoint Notification Service",
            "appRoles": []
        },
        {
            "displayName": "SharePoint Notification Service",
            "appRoles": []
        },
        {
            "displayName": "SharePoint Online Client",
            "appRoles": []
        },
        {
            "displayName": "SharePoint Online Client Extensibility",
            "appRoles": []
        },
        {
            "displayName": "SharePoint Online Client Extensibility Web Application Principal",
            "appRoles": []
        },
        {
            "displayName": "SharePoint Online Client Extensibility Web Application Principal Helper",
            "appRoles": []
        },
        {
            "displayName": "SharePoint Online Web Client Extensibility",
            "appRoles": []
        },
        {
            "displayName": "SharePoint Online Web Client Extensibility Isolated",
            "appRoles": []
        },
        {
            "displayName": "SharePointAdmin",
            "appRoles": []
        }
    ]
}
```

Can someone please point me out how to get this out? Again, this is tenant-specific and not the same that you would get from the MS documentation or by reverse engineering the Application endpoint with a handmade app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The official name is **Office 365 SharePoint Online**

```
GET /v1.0/servicePrincipals?$filter=displayName eq 'Office 365 SharePoint Online'&$select=id,displayName,appRoles,appId
```

`appId` should be unique across all tenants

```
GET /v1.0/servicePrincipals?$filter=appId eq '00000003-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000'&$select=id,displayName,appRoles,appId
```

App id for **Office 365 SharePoint Online** `00000003-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000`

App id for **Microsoft Graph** `00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000`